# About Generalized Hermite interpolation

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, spline

I am currently studying numerical method. I understand that the regular way of cubic Hermite interpolation on arbitrary interval $[a,b]$ is:

$ p(u)=\left( \begin{array}{c} 2t^3-3t^3+1\\ t^3-2t^2+t\\ -2t^3+3t^2\\ t^3-t^2\\ \end{array}\right)^T \left( \begin{array}{c} p(a)\\ (b-a)p'(a)\\ p(b)\\ (b-a)p'(b)\\ \end{array}\right)$, where $t=\frac{u-a}{b-a}$

But I don't know how to approach the following example. Can anyone tell me an approach to it? Thanks!(I don't get it what it means 'minimal degree')

Given $p(0)=0,p(1)=2,p(2)=18$ and derivatives $p'(0)=1,p'(2)=33$. Use the generalized Hermite interpolation scheme to develop the interpolation conditions for a curve $p(u)$ of minimal degree that interpolates the given points and derivatives at the respective knots. Compute the generalized Hermite polynomials and the interpolating curve.

Comment: This the fourth question you have asked about Bezier curves and Hermite interpolation. I have answered two of them. I might answer the other two also, if I get some response to the two answers I already gave you.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the "generalized Hermite polynomials" are the functions of $u$ that you get by substituting $t = (u-a)/(b-a)$ into $2t^3-3t^3+1$, $t^3-2t^2+t$, $-2t^3+3t^2$, $t^3-t^2$.

Then just apply the formula you wrote.

Don't worry about the "minimal degree" requirement. Your formula will give you a curve of degree 3, and this is the lowest degree that allows you to interpolate two values and two derivatives.

Comment: What you said is correct on the condition that if I only give you the condition $p(0)=0,p(2)=18,p'(0)=1,p'(2)=33$. But in our example, we have one more condition $p(1)=2$. This is the place I am confused, because we must use it somewhere and I don't know where we should use it.

Comment: Sorry. I missed the additional point.

Comment: @Cancan: The fact is that there's a missing data: $p'(1)$, without that you can't do Hermite curve interpolation. (If you hasn't solve this question yet.) :-)